# Why call sscanf() with argv[] can only use once?

Tags: c, argv, scanf

I need to get argv[1] and argv[2] to different types. I found that I could only use sscanf() once or the next string in argv cannot be retrieved.
Here's my code.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char t;
    float temp;
    sscanf(argv[1], "-%[cf]",&t);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Only the first sscanf() can get the formatted value.
How could I also get done with argv[2]?

Comment: What's the value of `argc`. What's inside `argv[2]`?

Comment: This should work if `argv[2]` is a correctly formatted float.

Comment: How do you know it's not working as you expect?  Anyway, do present an example command line with which you are calling this program.

Comment: I used makefile to run test. Here is my test:
 ./part4 -f 50.0

Answer (score 3):

Attempt to save string data in a `char` leading to undefined behavior (UB).

`"%[]"` expects to match a character array.

```
// char t;
// sscanf(argv[1], "-%[cf]",&t);

char t[100];
if (sscanf(argv[1], "-%99[cf]",t) != 1) Handle_Failure();
```

Recommend:
Add the width limit, like 99, to limit string input. Set to 1 less than the size of `t`.
Check the return value of `sscanf()`.